# Codignater Data Selecting

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

My database table structure:

[image: Data Base Table Structure]

Please Help.

I'm using codeigniter framework for this. I need display this data structure in my view.

---

**My View file like this:**

User Name01
 
Hobby01 Hobby02

User Name02 
Hobby01 Hobby02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should check codeigniter active records and the join function. you can achieve it with the following query:

```
$query = $this->db->select("*")
    ->from('users')
    ->join('hobbies', 'user.id', '=', 'hobby.user_id')
    ->get()
    ->result_array();
```

you can now var_dump $query to check ur data and format it accordingly.